# Instalacion Web

Tags: c#, mvc

estoy desarrollando una web en .net c# mvc.
actualmente la web funciona bien, pero antes de ponerla ya en Real he querido hacer una prueba de instalación así que he dado de alta una web en el IIS y he copiado el contenido de toda la web que tengo actualmente.

al abrir la web nueva de pruebas, no da errores, funciona bien, pero la visualización esta mal. se ve como añado en la imagen.

a que es devido esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Copiaste el contenido? no hiciste un deploy? es muy probable que te falten paquetes de cosas...

Comment: Gracias gbianchi.Inicialmente hice el deploy, al ver que me pasaba esto, hice la copia de la web actual. Otras veces lo he hecho así y nunca ha ido mal. total es crear una web y copiar el contenido de la web actual en la nueva carpeta. Voy a seguir investigando, pero quería preguntar por ver quien respondía..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser un problema con los permisos de los ficheros, acceso a carpetas, rutas, etc...

Un vistazo al log de errores debería ser suficiente para identificar el problema, pero como no lo pones...

De forma general:

- revisa los permisos de los ficheros
- revisa los permisos de las carpetas
- revisa el fichero .htaccess a ver si hay una ruta mal
- revisa las rutas absolutas en la base de datos a ver si se apunta a otra carpeta distinta
- revisa que los ficheros estén dentro de las carpetas permitidas por el servidor
- revisa la consola del navegador a ver el error que sale
- revisa los logs del servidor a ver el error que arroja
- revisa las rutas en el html, principalmente a los css, ya que parece que no carga el css